# Create device type schemas missing

Tags: ibm-cloud, jsonschema, watson-iot

I'm trying to add a Schema on the IoT Plataform Watson IBM using this tutorial above.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/im_schemas.html#iotrtinsights_task

The problem is that the button Manage Schema doesn't exist. After going to Devices, there is no Manage Schemas, there is just no button where it would suppose to be.
Go to Devices > Manage Schemas and click Add Schema.

My acconunt is logged in US South, so there is no European problem as the comments in other post here.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the changes that were announced in the [blog post](https://developer.ibm.com/iotplatform/2018/03/01/alternative-approach-defining-rules-iot-data/) dated 1st March.  To quote from the post:

> This is part of a wider program of changes to improve the way Watson™ IoT Platform delivers rules and actions.  As such we will be introducing some restrictions to the access to existing rules features whilst we make these changes.  If you have any further questions please contact IBM for further support.

Comment: In addition, here is information about the schema restrictions: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/information_management/im_reference.html#schema-restrictions